# ResourceLoader is throwing exception

Tags: spring, file

I have a code like follows

```
public LocalFileStorage(String storageUrl, Resource storageDirectory) {
    this.storageUrl = storageUrl;
    try {
        this.storageDirectory = storageDirectory.getFile();
        this.storageDirectory.deleteOnExit();
        this.storageDirectory.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I call the class the follows.

```
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;  // from spring

LocalFileStorage pictureStorage = new LocalFileStorage(Url+ "/resources/", resourceLoader.getResource("/resources/"));
```

call to

```
 resourceLoader.getResource("/resources/")
```

throws exception. I thought ResourceLoader loads directory also because after all directory is also a file.

My structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, only anything inside `/WEB-INF/classes`, `/WEB-INF/lib`,  `/WEB-INF/...` will be added to the classpath and accessible through `ClassLoader.getResource()`. The folder you are trying to access is not in `WEB-INF` and will therefore not appear in the classpath.

Assuming you are using something similar to Maven, you should put resource files under `/src/main/resources`. When your project is built, those files will end up in `WEB-INF/classes`.